# How to update webview's url on setState flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to update webview's url with my setState. How to do that?

The initial url I haved set on constructor have been loaded successfully. But it's not working when I try load the new one through my drawer menu by onTap method.

```dart
...
class _MyWebState extends State<MyWeb> {
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  final Set<String> _favorites = Set<String>();
  String url;
  Widget web;

  _MyWebState() {
    web = WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://my.flazhost.com',
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MyWeb'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          NavigationControls(_controller.future),
          Menu(_controller.future, () => _favorites),
        ],
      ),
      body: web,
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: FlutterLogo(
                size: 20,
              ),
              title: Text('Web AlQudwah'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  web = WebView(
                    initialUrl: 'https://flazhost.com',
                    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                      _controller.complete(webViewController);
                    },
                  );
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _bookmarkButton(),
    );
  }
}
...
```

How to update webview's url onTap method? Please help?

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the flutter webview for a long time, and I'm still not very happy with it...

But the key is the WebController instance that you get from the onWebViewCreated method of the webview. The instance of the initialized WebViewController has a method called loadUrl('your_new_url')

So you can just call following in your onTap handler:

```
onTap: () { 
   _controller.loadUrl('your_new_url');
}
```

When working with WebViews in flutter I experienced problems when using setState, because it will trigger a rebuild of whole page including the webview which gets reinitialized and of course reloads the page...

But that is mostly not the desired result, so if you want to controll the webview (wheater it will be changes to url, going back in browser history or executing javascript) you should handle it over the WebController initialized from the onWebViewCreated method

Here are the most used methods of the WebViewController class:

```
_controller.currentUrl() // Gets current url from WebView
_controller.loadUrl('your_new_url'); // Loads new url
_controller.evaluateJavascript('your js code as a string') // Execute JS over WebView console
_controller.goBack() // Goes one step back in browser history
_controller.goForward() // Goes one step forwards in browser history
_controller.clearCache() // Clears cache of WebView
```

It's really confusing and badly documented (espacially for beginners like me), so I hope the flutter team will provide us with more detailed information and tutorials